# Spring boot with Liquibase not executing in Docker

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker, liquibase

I'm new to Docker and I've been trying to implement the containerization of database(Postgresql) and API(Spring Boot with liquibase). However, it seems like the liquibase is not running. Please see the following for your reference. Thanks in advance.

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/demo
spring.datasource.username=compose-postgres
spring.datasource.password=compose-postgres
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:db/liquibase-changelog.xml
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '2'

 services:
   api:
     image: 'docker-spring-boot-postgres:latest'
     build:
       context: .
     container_name: api
     depends_on:
       - db
     environment:
       - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/demo
       - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=compose-postgres
       - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=compose-postgres
       - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
     ports:
       - "8080:8080"
  db:
    image: 'postgres:13.1-alpine'
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=compose-postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=compose-postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=demo
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

**liquibase-changelog.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="https://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
    https://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

  <include file="changelog/01-createTableUser-changelog.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

  <!-- more <include> tags go here -->
</databaseChangeLog>
```

**liquibase directory structure:**

[image]

**command used to run:**

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up
```

Comment: May we see the error?  I just see configuration (thanks for detailed documentation) but don't see the error.

Answer (score 1):

I see have provided all the configuration. Can you also provide what error are your receiving, what liquibase commands are you using?